# Permission denied in AUR helper paru

Tags: arch-linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, aur

Recently, I tried the Archlinux on WSL2. But I got into trouble when I used Paru as the AUR helper to install some packages like bochs. It said:

```
error: Permission denied (os error 13)
```

I knew it was probably caused by the wrong owner of `.cargo` and `.rustup,` according to this [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/6757). But it was ineffective after I used `chown`, changing the owner of `.cargo` and `.rustup` recursively.

So, does anyone know how to solve it?

BTW: I did not have logs either. There is nothing about the process of installing in file `pacman.log`.

The commands I used:

```
paru -S bochs
sudo chown -R username:usergroup .cargo .rustup
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include all relevant commands. What `paru` command did you run? What `chown` commands did you run?

Comment: And presumably `username:usergroup` are the user name and group of the user who tried to run the `paru` command, right?

Comment: @terdon, Yes, the `username` and the `usergroup` is the user name and group of the executor.